# Create multiple instances of class to match XML

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I have been provided the following XML request as a model to follow along with the WSDL.

```
  <xs:complexType name="commonInput">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="propertyList" nillable="true" type="tns:commonProperty" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="commonProperty">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="context" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="value" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I am expected to create a response in code using these types to create something similar to the following

```
     <commonInput>
        <loginId></loginId>
        <propertyList>
           <context></context>
           <name></name>
           <value></value>
        </propertyList>
        <propertyList>
           <context></context>
           <name></name>
           <value></value>
        </propertyList>
     </commonInput>
```

The issue I'm encountering is that I cannot figure out how to create this structure in code since the commonInput.propertyList is not an array or list, it is simply a class.
How can I create multiple instances of propertyList within the commonInput?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class `commonInput` has an attribute called `propertyList`, which is a sequence of entities of type `commonProperty`. Note the `<xs:sequence>` tags that enclose its definition.

So you should be able to use something like:

`private List<CommonProperty> propertyList = new ArrayList<CommonProperty>();`

---

I'm not exactly sure what translation you use from XML to your "class".
We use Jaxb to translate between XML and java classes automatically.

In response to your comment, I will try to clarify with an example:
Our WSDL defines:

```
<s:complexType name="ArrayOfTEKLeverancierObj">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="TEKLeverancierObj" 
             nillable="true" type="tns:TEKLeverancierObj" />
        </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

And in our java class this translates to:

```
public class ArrayOfTEKLeverancierObj {

    @XmlElement(name = "TEKLeverancierObj", nillable = true)
    protected List<TEKLeverancierObj> tekLeverancierObj;
```

Comment: I understand that portion of it but my concern is assigning the List<> to the commonInput.propertyList.  Since it's not defined as a list (simply a class) can I do that?  I don't believe that will work.

Comment: Updated my answer with some working example code from our own application. Hopefully this will help?

Comment: Thanks.  This did help to understand the structure.  Ultimately the issue was that I needed to convert the List to an array in our own code because of the way the schema was configured.

Comment: Glad it helped, and you were able to get it working.
Believe me, you're not the only one who has had headaches over WSDL's recently ;)